# once selenium web driver clicks any button, then it wont click any other button further

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I had a problem with the web driver while page get refresh
scenario: 
click on the 1st button and the page got refresh. Once the page refresh, then the driver cant able to find the position of the second button. the second button is save function so that I cant able to save that page.

The error which I got while running :

```
unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (257, 898).
```

Other element would receive the click:

```
<div id="divModel" class="dialog" style="display: block; height: 2037px; width: 1450px;">...</div>
```

1) is there any solution to refresh the variables on the page without refreshing the whole page?

2) is there any solution to find out the next button position after clicking the first one on that page?

Comment: please can you share your html code piece?

Comment: Please share your web driver code and html code of that save button.

Comment: i am using keyword driven framework code used for click function is              case "CLICK":
            //Perform click
            driver.findElement(this.getObject(p,objectName,objectType)).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
            break;

Comment: how you are finding that button? by xpath? id? please share that code.

Comment: if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("ID")){
             
            return By.id(p.getProperty(objectName));
        }

Comment: Please add any code or HTML in the comments into the question itself so others will see it and it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as we do not have any clear idea what happens with you. First thing checks that is your Xpath is changing after refreshing the page. another thing is may be your page need some wait.

Try below code:-

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("YOUR XPATH OR ANY LOCATOR"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By) element));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

At last if nothing work then try to use `Thread.sleep(5000);` .
It's not a good practice even it is not recommended to use `Thread.sleep` but you can at least try once to ensure that the problem is related to wait only

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution, it's workaround: if you use Chrome driver then use FF/IE driver instead. I encountered similar problem with Chrome driver not so long ago, turned out to be Chrome driver bug.

Also, if you use PO model, you can use @CacheLookup annotation:

```
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(id = "your_id")
private WebElement saveButton;
```

> Marker annotation to be applied to WebElements to indicate that it
>   never changes (that is, that the same instance in the DOM will always
>   be used)